# Generic class and simplified constrains?

Tags: c#, generics

Lets say I've got a generic interface `IFace<T, U>`. The `T` and `U` can be constrained in some additional way, but I don't think this is relevant to the problem.

I'd like to create a new generic class `GenClass` with the following definition:

`class GenClass<T> where T: IFace`

I.e. I'd like to tell the compiler that `GenClass` should handle any implementation of `IFace` without specifying the generic types.

Is this possible, or do I NEED to specify the `T` and `U` generic parameters?

I've tried writing `IFace` as well as `IFace<>` or `IFace<,>`, but the compiler always threw a fit - so I'm thinking this cannot be done. Still, perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way?

Comment: The `IFace<T,U>` interface makes no sense without having classes specified for `T` and `U`. What behaviour are you hoping for? ie can you give some examples of the sort of code you'd like to write? It sounds like you are either mistaken about what generics are or you are trying to solve a problem in the wrong way...

Comment: @Chris In reality I'm trying to create a helper method for a service locator which registers TWO distinct implementations of an interface (and one of those implementations is a bit more constrained than the other). The problem is that the base interface already has two generic parameters, so the helper class would need to have 5 (!!) generic parameters to compile, which is really ugly (albeit this WOULD work). As such, I was wondering if there isn't a way to simplify things.

Comment: Ah. I see roughly where you are coming from. I'm wondering if you should ask another question with the code you have asking whether it can be simplified. Not sure if it might be best put on codreview.stackexchange.com (disclaimer: I don't hang out there so I only have vague ideas of what is on topic so please do check) since the code works, you just want to know if it can be made more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this possible, or do I NEED to specify the T and U generic parameters?

You need them, I'm afraid. You'll need to have

```
class GenClass<T, TX, TY> where T : IFace<TX, TY>
```

That's assuming you can't create a non-generic `IFace` interface that the generic one derives from - that's often the simplest approach:

```
public interface IFace
{
    // Include anything that doesn't need the type parameters here
}

public interface IFace<T1, T2> : IFace
{
    // Include anything that needs the type parameters here
}
```

*Then* you can have:

```
class GenClass<T> where T : IFace
```

because now the non-generic interface really does exist.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that. The closest you can get is the following:

```
interface IFace { }
interface IFace<T, U>: IFace { }
class GenClass<T> where T: IFace
```

Otherwise your stuck with:

```
class GenClass<T, TFace, UFace> where T: IFace<TFace, UFace>
```

Based on your question though, it seems like you are not interested in `TFace` and `UFace` in your `GenClass`, so the non generic interface should do.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following.

```
class GenClass<T, TT, TU> where T: IFace<TT, TU>
```

And then when initialising the `GenClass` you can define all three parameters.

```
class MyFace<T, U> : IFace<T, U>

var instance = new GenClass<MyFace<string, int>>();
```

Or

```
class MyFace : IFace<string, int>

var instance = new GenClass<MyFace>();
```

---

If you want to provide a non generic base type which knows for example about two properties you could also do this.

```
interface IFace<T, U>
{
    T ValueOne { get; set; }
    U ValueTwo { get; set; }
}

abstract class FaceBase : IFace<object, object>
{
    public object ValueOne { get; set; }
    public object ValueTwo { get; set; }

    protected FaceBase(object valueOne, object valueTwo)
    {
        ValueOne = valueOne;
        ValueTwo = valueTwo;
    }
}

class GenClass<T> where T : FaceBase
{
    private T Value { get; set; }

    public GenClass()
    {
        // do something with Value.ValueOne or Value.ValueTwo
    }
}
```

An implementation of `FaceBase` would look like the following.

```
class MyFace : FaceBase, IFace<string, int>
{
    public new string ValueOne
    {
        get => base.ValueOne as string;
        set => base.ValueOne = value;
    }

    public new int ValueTwo
    {
        get => (int) base.ValueTwo;
        set => base.ValueTwo = value;
    }

    public MyFace(string valueOne, int valueTwo)
        : base(valueOne, valueTwo)
    { }
}
```

Comment: This is what I meant by "or do I NEED to specify the `T` and `U` generic parameters?" I'm trying to simplify the class definition, because specifying the `T` and `U` parameters on every use won't really serve any purpose in my case. :/

Comment: Also, creating a specific `IFace` implementation which has the specific types as `T` and `U` also won't work, as that makes the class I'm trying to build far less generic than it should be.

Comment: @Shaamaan I've added a second possiblity which still gives you access to the types (in the example in my post as an property).